# Pig Script Based On Grouping

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a data-set like this.

```
cus_ID  BRAND AMOUNT
1       5       10
2       4       20
3       5       15
1       5       20
1       4       30
2       3       15
```

I want to find top 5 brands and top 10 customer id's of each of those top 5 brands using PIG.

Comment: Hey! How about to show some of your work?

Comment: First took top 5 brands....and then used join operation for the customers for those 5 brands. And then took top 10 customers of those 5 brands....Query too long to put it in comments....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first goal (find top 5 brands), here you go (code not tested):

```
mydata = LOAD ... <load your data from your file or other source>
grouped = GROUP mydata BY brand;
flattened = FOREACH grouped GENERATE
    FLATTEN(group) AS brand,
    SUM(mydata.amount) AS amount_per_brand;
topfivebrand = LIMIT (ORDER flattened by amount_per_brand DESC) 5;
dump topfivebrand;
```

That should get you started! :)